# One of which being hand selected, by ____, as the _____

Tags: grammar

I am writing a very important personal statement for career progression. I started a few of my sentences to show examples of accomplishments with "One of which being" and when I had someone review it for feedback they told me I was using improper English and I should change my writing style, is this true? How could I improve it to make it more impactful?

Comment: If you repeated the phrase "one of which being" several times in the same document, that is bad style.

Comment: If this is about something in the past, I think "One of which was hand selected, ..." would possibly work better.